# C# - open browser to intranet on button click

Tags: c#

I am aware

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.facebook.com");
```

Goes to facebook but i want a button for a handy shortcut to the networks Intranet.
I obviously cant just put

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("intranet");
```

Which is what i normally put in the browser, so how do i direct the button click here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Comment: "obviously" - it may be obvious to you (and I think I have a pretty good guess), but please explain *what* is obvious to you. That way you will get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type "intranet" into the browser's address bar, the browser silently adds `http://`. When you copy the address from that address bar (after your intranet has loaded), you will get the full URL.

Try and use that in your `Process.Start`.